# How to generate ASW s3 presigned URl from php and then upload multiple files in that url from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I want to upload multiple files from browser with `axios` into s3 bucket. I am using `aws-sdk-php` library in `laravel`. My intention is when I want to upload one or multiple files,

1. I will send a `GET` request to backend(laravel) for a presigned URL.
2. After receiving the URL I will make a `PUT/POST` request to that URL with all the files.

I have read the `aws-sdk-php` docs and found some problems with my intention.

1. I have seen that I need to give a `Object Key` when I want to generate a presigned URL. In the docs and other articles they are using file_name as `Key`. But for my purpose I cannot send multiple file_names since it doesn't make sense.
2. Then I thought of generating a UUID and use it as Key. But then how would I access my files individually later? I didn't get any reference to that part.

Can anyone help me with these problem?

Comment: you need to generate one URL per file to be uploaded. The AWS SDK does not support multiple file uploads in a single request as far as I know that's just AWS CLI and Console "trickery".